# C++ access to static class member variables, not friend

Tags: c++, class, static

I'm sorry in advance if this is a stupid or nonsense question, but:

Can a non-constant static class variable for one class be used by another class without using friend or base/derived classes?  The (abbreviated) situation is:

```
class Decl {
    public:
          static string searchVal;
          ... (other irrelevant stuff)
};

class Conj {
    public:
        static string searchVal;
        ... (other irrelevant stuff)
};
```

I don't want to repeat searchVal in both classes, and because of the rest of the program, I'm not keen on using friend (but I will if it's the only option).

Comment: You can access the static member anywhere using `Decl::searchVal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `static` members are `public`, if your class definitions are both visible, then their static members can be accessed using `Decl::searchVal` or `Conj::searchVal` respectively.

For example

```
class Decl 
{
     public: static string searchVal;
};

class Conj
{
    public:
        static string searchVal;
};

// within ANY function, including members of either class above
//    ... as long as both definitions above are visible to the compiler

 if (Conj::searchVal == Decl::searchVal)
 {
       // do something
 }
```